# Missing Launch Icon for Midlet on Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, midlet

I am using the 1.1 Blackberry Plugin for Eclipse to develop an application. I am able to create a Hello World program using BlackBerry native code, but I am unable to get a Midlet working. Unlike the Hello World which appears in Downloads, the Midlet doesn't appear, even after I attempt to manually open the .cod file. The Java app works if I run it as a Java ME project. How can I make it work?

**Links**

- [Could not run midlet on simulator](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/could-not-run-midlet-on-simulator/m-p/287711)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this thread](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/could-not-run-midlet-on-simulator/m-p/287711), the App Descriptor xml was did not have the Application Type set to MIDlet. I also set the title and the name of the main MIDlet class.